# Timestamps in Cognito Forms

Tags: forms, webforms

I'm trying to figure out how to configure a calculation field in Cognito Forms to display a timestamp when another field is filled out.

For example:

```
Name Field #1 = Bob
Timestamp Field #1 = Timestamp when "Bob" was entered into Name Field #1
Name Field #2 = Nancy 
Timestamp Field #2 = Timestamp When "Nancy" was entered into Name Field #2
Name Field #3 = Null
Timestamp Field #3 = Null
```

When a user edits other parts of the form the timestamps will not update. Only when that specific field is updated, edited or revised should the timestamp associated with that field update.

I was told I would need to pass the timestamps as strings using a calculation field set to the text option but I don't understand how to stop these fields from updating every time the form is edited or submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create two date fields: one for the date and the other for the time.

Set both to be either invisible or visible internally.

**DateField1**: Set the type to 'date' and default value = if NameField1 = null then null else DateTime.Today

**TimeField1**: Set the type to 'time' and default value = if NameField1 = null then null else DateTime.Now

Then create a calculation field. You can have it become visible when `NameField1` != null

This calculation field will be your timestamp.

**Timestamp1**: `DateField1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")+" at "+TimeField1.ToString("hh:mm tt")`

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I've found that using any kind of date/time calculation in Cognito simply inputs the runtime date and time, so it's not a true timestamp. The only effective way is to have the user input the date and time. Unfortunately.